# Fill inside a concave polygon based on its border

Tags: matplotlib, drawing, polygon

The question is to draw a 8 point star with it's inside coloured, using pylab, numpy & matplot.

I've already set the vertices xy coordinates, which gives the border of the star:

```
a=linspace(0,2*pi,2*n-1)
x=[]
y=[]
per=0

ang=list(a)

for i in range(2*n-1):
    if i%2==0:
        x.append(cos(ang[i]))
        y.append(sin(ang[i]))
    else:
        x.append(0.5*cos(ang[i]))
        y.append(0.5*sin(ang[i]))
plot (x,y)
```

Now i need to fill it, but i didn't managed to find a solution to it.

EDIT:

I inserted this line:

```
u=linspace(0,1)
for k in u:
    for i in range(2*n-1):
        if i%2==0:
            x.append(k*cos(ang[i]))
            y.append(k*sin(ang[i]))
        else:
            x.append(0.5*k*cos(ang[i]))
            y.append(0.5*k*sin(ang[i]))
```

And by simple math concept of area, integrals and etc problem solved (:

Answer (score 1):

The loop could be easily vectorized in numpy and filled polygon could be plotted by matplotlib `fill` command. Here is example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 8
# angles of outer points
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, tips+1)
# generate outer and inner (shifted) coordinates
x = np.array([np.sin(phi),
              0.5 * np.sin(phi + phi[1]/2)]).flatten(order='F')
y = np.array([np.cos(phi),
              0.5 * np.cos(phi + phi[1]/2)]).flatten(order='F')
# plot filled
plt.fill(x,y)
plt.show()
```